# Route/Tunnel property value to another property with a behavior

Tags: wpf, behavior

I have a `DataGrid` and want to pass the `AlternationIndex` to the bound element (off the current object).

**CellTemplate**

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Index}"/>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:RoutePropertyValue 
                    Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"
                    Target="{Binding Index, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

*RoutePropertyValueBehavior**

```
public class RoutePropertyValue : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The source property value
    /// </summary>
    public object Source
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(SourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Source"/> DependencyProperty.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(object), typeof(RoutePropertyValue), new PropertyMetadata(null, SourceChangedCallback));

    private static void SourceChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (d is RoutePropertyValue instance)
        {
            instance.OnSourceChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnSourceChanged()
    {
        Target = Source;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// The target where the value should be writetn
    /// </summary>
    public object Target
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(TargetProperty);
        set => SetValue(TargetProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Target"/> DependencyProperty.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Target", typeof(object), typeof(RoutePropertyValue), new PropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

Actually the `Target` is always `null` when debugging. Also if changing the order inside of the `DataGrid`, the `SourceChangedCallback` is not getting called again. So anyways it seems to be the wrong way to 'tunnel' property values to another property.

Comment: Every cell? This template is only used in one cell, so only on instance per cell and row is created (correct me if Im wrong). What I want to achieve is, that every cell got a `ComboBox` to select an index != its own. After 'editing' I also need the index of every element and want to avoit anoter iteration on the `DataGrid` just for getting the depending index.

Comment: What is Index? Is it a property of your data object?

Comment: @mm8 exactly! The `Index` should be the `AlternationIndex` of the `DataGrid` and always set/updated if the data object on the `DataGrid` changes its position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind to the target object and then specify which source property you want to set. You should try to set the source property whenever any of the target properties are set. Try this:

```
public class RoutePropertyValue : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    public object Source
    {
        get => GetValue(SourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Source), typeof(object), 
        typeof(RoutePropertyValue), new PropertyMetadata(null, Callback));

    private static void Callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (d is RoutePropertyValue instance)
            instance.OnAnyValueChanged();
    }

    protected virtual void OnAnyValueChanged()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TargetMember))
            TargetObject?.GetType().GetProperty(TargetMember)?.SetValue(TargetObject, Source);
    }

    public object TargetObject
    {
        get => GetValue(TargetObjectProperty);
        set => SetValue(TargetObjectProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TargetObject), typeof(object), 
        typeof(RoutePropertyValue), new PropertyMetadata(null, Callback));

    public string TargetMember
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TargetMemberProperty);
        set => SetValue(TargetMemberProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetMemberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TargetMember), typeof(string),
        typeof(RoutePropertyValue), new PropertyMetadata(null, Callback));
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<behaviors:RoutePropertyValue 
    TargetObject="{Binding}"
    TargetMember="Index"
    Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"
    />
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to write directly in the property that the `TargetObject` gets updated?

Comment: You want to set a property of an object. You don't want to bind the source property to a target property.